# Как сделать проигрывание видео с YouTube при наведении?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, youtube

Всем привет! Хотелось бы сделать у себя такое же отображение видео как и на ютуб т.е при наведении на изображение чтобы производилось видео. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать!?

[image: Щас так]

[image: А нужно так]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `onmouseover` для каждого элемента, а внутри функции запускайте видео. Возможно вам еще понадобится останавливать видео. А для этого есть `onmouseout`

```
videoArray.forEach((item) => {
        item.onmouseover = () => {
            item.playVideo()
        }
    })
```

Comment: Ещё нужно добавить проверку на воспроизведение.

Comment: А как добавить проверку?